# How to use ui-router states with directives and "controller as" syntax?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

When using ui-router, I setup states like so:

```
$stateProvider
  .state 'product',
    url: '/catalog/product',
    templateUrl: 'app/product/product.html',
```

The only problem is, I have my controller in a directive, not as a stand-alone controller service. So how do I tell ui-router to hit my directive instead of the template?

Otherwise I'm not sure how to bind the template scope to the controller defined in my directive.

Comment: If you have a directive inside your template then that directive's controller will automatically come into action. No need to tell ui-router.

Answer (score 6):

If you insist on Directive, as a target for your state template, the way would be :

```
$stateProvider
  .state 'product',
    url: '/catalog/product',
    template: '<div here-is-my-directive-with-all-its-standard-settings></div>',
```

*NOTE: there does not have to be `controller` explicitly defined for view at all. Just the HTML template will be injected into position in parent*

And the directive:

```
.directive('hereIsMyDirectiveWithAllItsStandardSettings', ...)
```

Other words, the `UI-Router` is handling states, and injecting the **`template`**. The template contains directive, which can do what was designed for... as expected...

Comment: How would you pass parent scope variables to your template directive, assuming it has isolate scope?